# How do I trust localhost with Intercom Messenger? (Remix Run)

Tags: intercom, remix.run

I'm trying to integrate Intercom into my Remix Run app. Intercom asks you to list trusted domains on which the messenger should work. The official documentation states that

> 'We don't support adding localhost, but you can add '0.0.0.0' and/or
> '127.0.0.1' and the Messenger will work on these domains.'

I have added these IP addresses to my list of trusted domains, but I still can't get it to work. When running on localhost, I find a request with error 403 in the Network tab with the message: "This domain has not been trusted for the Intercom app defined in the JavaScript snippet.". What am I doing wrong?

[See my Trusted Domains configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H1Uk.png)

Comment: Have you tried visiting your localhost via `0.0.0.0:portnumber`?